# MVC NHibernate - prevent user to update other user's data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

what is the proper way to prevent user from deleting/updating other user's data in MVC/NHibernate application?

I have an entity which has foreign key (UserId) and I update it using `Session.Update(entity)`.
How to add a `Where` or `Join` clause to `Update` call to restrict such action?

I could of course check if the user executing MVC action is the same as `entity.UserId`, but this would require an additional select.

Could you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps take a look at the multi tenancy support with filters, interceptors,...

http://www.agileatwork.com/bolt-on-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-with-unity-and-nhibernate-part-ii-commingled-data/

Comment: I like the idea of filters, however the example on the page you provided is not working. It's because in the interceptor's OnSave method the propertyNames[] doesn't contain this private field tenant of entity and I cannot update it's value in the state[]